# server doesn't listen postgresql 9.1 after service change

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql, windows-server-2012-r2

I did Install PostgreSQL 9.1 on my 2012 R2 windows server It did installed successfully now I changed PostgreSQL service account

Facing error when trying to restart PostgreSQL service !

> The PostgreSQL 9.1 service on local computer started and then stopped.
>   Some services stooped automatically if they are not in use by other
>   services or programs.

When I am trying to login to PostgreSQL database facing the below errors

> Server Doesn't listen

I checked config file

```
listen_addresses = '*'  
port = 5432
```

Don't know what the error is please help me guys 
I am pretty new to PostgreSQL

Comment: Try starting it from command prompt and see what error you are getting. Refer to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html

Comment: *"now I changed PostgreSQL service account"*. What/how? Details please.

Comment: I did add a service account and restated it successfully now how to know the status of PostgreSQL server is running on which service